# Is it bad that this ad makes zillions of requests?

Tags: javascript, ios, rendering, paint, ads

We've been asked to run a particular kind of video ad on the mobile version of our site I've not seen before. To get around iOS restrictions on autoplay of videos, it creates the animation using a series of timers which continually fire off a request every quarter second or so for thumbnail images in base64 data encoded format.

You can hopefully see the requests it makes in this developer tools screenshot. The ad in question is the right-hand thumbnail in the middle row - the other thumbnails are our own articles.

[image]

Each request is a frame of the animation:

[image]

Each update of the thumbnail seems to trigger a browser repaint. The repaints stop when you scroll the ad out of view, as you can see by the break in the green Composite Tile Worker bar in this timeline view.

[image]

After the first loading, requests are fetched from the browser cache.

We're concerned about carrying an ad of this sort on our site. Apart from it being quite a bad user experience to force autoplay "video" on our readers, a piece of JavaScript that is continuously making several timed requests per second may affect browser performance on mobiles and may even crash them. At the very least it may introduce a jag into scrolling. Are we right to be concerned?

Comment: How about making a sprite?

Comment: It's not really in my control, I'd just like to understand if there's anything necessarily bad in this way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've answered your own question.  If your web site was a shop would you want your customers pissed-off?  Would they come again?   What would they tell others?